# Regex find and replace with changed content

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to find number in javascript and replace it with value that depends on that number.

Source string:

```
abc20.0xxxxxx30xxx
```

Regex has to find double, divide it with 5 and replace the value.

Expected result should look like:

```
abc4.0xxxxxx6.0xxx
```

Really thanks

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. You have the ability to delete your own post.

Comment: where ? i dont want help from people like jan

Comment: ^^ Well other people can still help you.

Comment: ya, it was fast, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```js
function divideByFive(s) {
    return s.replace(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g, function (a) { 
        a = parseFloat(a) / 5;
        return a.toFixed(1); 
    });
}


// I/O 

var inp = document.querySelector('input');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

inp.oninput = function () {
    // Get input
    var s = inp.value;
    // Transform
    var res = divideByFive(s);
    // Output
    div.textContent = res;
}

inp.oninput();
```

```html
<input value="abc20.0xxxxxx30xxx">
<div></div>
```

Just run the above snippet to see how that function transforms the text as you type.

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method is used with a regular expression and a [call back function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), which is called for each match.

Comment: Nice to hear you appreciate it!